# Android: How to handle error in try catch without force close

Tags: android

When I run an asynctask to connect to an HTTP server, I want to display error message when it cannot connect to server. Instead, the app forcefully closes on error, without displaying the error message. I want to display error message when error occurs instead of crashing, but it just shows alert dialog with message error(e.getMessage()) in body description alert dialog.

Below is my code:

```
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();

        urlConnection.connect();
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        data = sb.toString();
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        ErrorDialog(e.getMessage());
    }

    return data;
 }

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    String data = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            ErrorDialog(e.getMessage());
        }

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null && result.length() < 0) {
            ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
            listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
        }
    }
}

private void ErrorDialog(String Description) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            ListCategoryActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("You get Error...");
    alertDialog.setMessage(Description);
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning);

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Logcat error:

```
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:107)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:913)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:931)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at com.haichal.codefive.ListCategoryActivity.ErrorDialog(ListCategoryActivity.java:327)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at com.haichal.codefive.ListCategoryActivity.downloadUrl(ListCategoryActivity.java:150)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at com.haichal.codefive.ListCategoryActivity.access$2(ListCategoryActivity.java:125)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at com.haichal.codefive.ListCategoryActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(ListCategoryActivity.java:162)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at com.haichal.codefive.ListCategoryActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(ListCategoryActivity.java:1)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-23 11:58:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(5776):     ... 5 more
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776): Activity com.haichal.codefive.ListCategoryActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41410d58 that was originally added here
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.haichal.codefive.ListCategoryActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41410d58 that was originally added here
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at com.haichal.codefive.ListCategoryActivity.startDownload(ListCategoryActivity.java:100)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at com.haichal.codefive.ListCategoryActivity.initFromDb(ListCategoryActivity.java:91)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at com.haichal.codefive.ListCategoryActivity.onCreate(ListCategoryActivity.java:54)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1923)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1150)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
01-23 11:58:38.079: E/WindowManager(5776):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Logcat verbose e.getMessage();

```
01-23 11:58:36.909: D/HaichalLog(5776): failed to connect to 
  /192.168.103.121 (port 80): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

Thanks.

Comment: check permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file as  INTERNET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your dialog separate from the UI thread .Just try out this way:

> ```
>  private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
>     String data = null;
>     @Override
>     protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
>        try {
>             data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
>           } catch (IOException e) {
>            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
>         runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
>           public void run() {
>                  ErrorDialog(e.getMessage());
>                 }
>      });
>     }
> }
>         return data;
>     }
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>         if (result != null && result.length() < 0) {
>             ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
>             listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
>         }
>     }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Solved with this, but before it I move String downloadUrl to try asyntask DownloadTask. And I remove method String downloadurl. Thanks brother, i give you true answer and one vote.

Answer (score 3):

as in log :

> RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not
>   called Looper.prepare()

because you are trying to show AlertDialog from AsyncTask's doInBackground and we are not able to update UI elements from doInBackground method . change your code as to handle execution in doInBackground :

```
String strcatcherror="";
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
    try {
        data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        strcatcherror="";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        strcatcherror=e.getMessage();

    }

    return data;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(!strcatcherror.equals("")){
         if (result != null && result.length() < 0) {
           ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
           listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
         }
       }
     else{
             // show error message here
             ErrorDialog(strcatcherror);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 ErrorDialog(e.getMessage());
```

you can not Call **alert dialogue inside doInBackground()**.

so the Alternativce way is placing global variable like XYZ inside Asyc Class and set the e.getMessage() to that Variable XYZ inside catch block. and check whether that variable is empty or not and Execute    ErrorDialog(XYZ); inside onPostExecute() method.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly display alert dialog from doinbackground(). Either you need to call it from runOnUIThread() or call from postExecute() or send a message to activity handler.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, still not working, i think problem in downloadUrl

Comment: Solved with answer Grishu;

Answer (score 0):

Urlconnection has setTimeout method.
Catch it with a SocketTimeOutException (which will be thrown back to the caller).
Handle it with a Toast.